# \printbibliography of a single item

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

It is possible to use `\printbibliography` (or some other command) to print (in the same way `\printbibliograhy` do) a single entry of a .bib file given it's key/identifier (autor:year for example)?

More generally, given a beamer presentation, where some frame contain a `\nocite{}` command, it is possible to use `\printbiblography` to print only the reference(s) `\nocite`-d in that frame?

Comment: Are looking for something like `\begin{refsection}
\nocite{DonaldDuck}
\printbiblography
\end{refsection}`?

Comment: If this does not help, can you please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: I understand this and I think this will works, but it is possible, at least, to create a `refsection`for every frame automatically? or do you think there is a better approach?

Comment: `refsection` can probably be done automatically. Not printing the bibligraphy but using `\fullcite` might also be an alternative. But if we would have a MWE to have something to start with, it would be much less work to answer.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to answer without more information. But it sounds like there would be two possibilities.

1. with `\begin{refsection} \nocite{...} \printbibliography \end{refsection}` only the references from within this section will be printed

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}

   \usepackage{biblatex}
   \addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

   \begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
   \begin{refsection} 
   \nocite{knuth:ct}
   \printbibliography 
   \end{refsection} 
   \end{frame}
   \end{document}
   ```

[image]

2. `\fullcite{}` will give you something similar to the entry in the bibliography. So instead of using `\nocite`, use `\fullcite` at the end of a frame.

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}

   \usepackage{biblatex}
   \addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

   \begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
   \fullcite{knuth:ct}
   \end{frame}
   \end{document}
   ```

[image]

(If you use this approach in a class which shows the bib heading, it might be useful to combine this with `\printbibliography[heading=none]` -- thanks to @tobiasBora)

Comment: Note that you might want to add `\printbibliography[heading=none]` if you want to remove the title of the section.

Comment: @tobiasBora In beamer the bib heading isn't printed

Comment: Oh, I was using your answer on a standard article document, in that case `[heading=none]` is required.

Comment: @tobiasBora I added a comment to the answer